# Storing a tree of arbitrary objects in yaml file

Tags: python, serialization, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I simply want to use YAML to store my dedicated Python objects representing a configuration and load it back when needed.
My application allows to define a scenario that is made of nested Python objects.
The root object (name it Scenario) contains some attributes and a list of objects (name them Level1Type1, Level1Type2,...),
and each of these Level1 objects is made also of some attributes and a list of objects (name them Level2Type1, Level2Type2,...).
To summarize, it is a tree. Each leaf has attributes and a list of other objects that are themselves leaves.
Moreover, only a part of the object's attributes, has to be saved in the file (dynamic attributes have no interest in a configuration file).
I decided to explicitly define which attributes are saved.

Reading the documents, retrieved by google on the subject "Python serialize objects with yaml", gave me some hints but let me confused
on what is really needed.
Most of them are provided by **Anthon** (many thanks to him). It mainly explains why I used ruamel.yaml.
One regret: I spent too much time on that subject due to the lack of explanations and documents about Python arbitrary objects serialization.

I noticed that the List objects in the scenario created with the object constructor becomes `CommentedSeq` objects when the scenario is reloaded using the YAML file.
I'm also wondering about the goal of the definition of `__repr__` that I saw in many examples. Is it used by serialization mechanism?

Hereafter is the code validating my needs for my application.

```
import ruamel.yaml
from io import StringIO

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

class Base:
    """
    Base class for every class in the tree.
    """
    # class variables can be necessary
    cst_value = "common"

    def __init__(self, elt_name=None, comment=None):
        self.elt_name = elt_name
        self.comment = comment

    def treatment(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('Base class should not be implemented')

@yaml.register_class
class Scenario(Base):

    yaml_tag = u'!Scenario'

    def __init__(self, elt_name=None, comment=None, level1_objs=None):
        super().__init__(elt_name, comment)
        # List of level1 objects: to be saved in yaml file.
        self.level1_objs = [] if level1_objs is None else level1_objs

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        dict_representation = {
            'elt_name': node.elt_name,
            'comment': node.comment,
            'level1_objs': node.level1_objs
        }
        return representer.represent_mapping(cls.yaml_tag, dict_representation)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        m = {}
        for m in constructor.construct_yaml_map(node):
            pass
        elt_name = m['elt_name'] if 'elt_name' in m else None
        comment = m['comment'] if 'comment' in m else None
        level1_objs = m['level1_objs'] if 'level1_objs' in m else None
        return cls(elt_name, comment, level1_objs)

    def treatment(self):
        pass


class BunchOfData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data_frame = None
        self.data1 = None
        self.data2 = None
        self.data3 = None


@yaml.register_class
class Level1Type1(Base):

    yaml_tag = u'!Level1Type1'

    def __init__(self, elt_name=None, comment=None, level2_objs=None, l1_t1_attr1=None):
        super().__init__(elt_name, comment)
        # List of level2 objects: to be saved in yaml file.
        self.level2_objs = [] if level2_objs is None else level2_objs
        # Attribute: to be saved in yaml file.
        self.l1_t1_attr1 = l1_t1_attr1
        # Dynamic attribute: Not to be saved in yaml file
        self.dyn_data = BunchOfData()

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        dict_representation = {
            'elt_name': node.elt_name,
            'comment': node.comment,
            'l1_t1_attr1': node.l1_t1_attr1,
            'level2_objs': node.level2_objs
        }
        return representer.represent_mapping(cls.yaml_tag, dict_representation)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        m = {}
        for m in constructor.construct_yaml_map(node):
            pass
        elt_name = m['elt_name'] if 'elt_name' in m else None
        comment = m['comment'] if 'comment' in m else None
        level2_objs = m['level2_objs'] if 'level2_objs' in m else None
        l1_t1_attr1 = m['l1_t1_attr1'] if 'l1_t1_attr1' in m else None
        return cls(elt_name, comment, level2_objs, l1_t1_attr1)

    def treatment(self):
        pass


@yaml.register_class
class Level1Type2(Base):

    yaml_tag = u'!Level1Type2'

    def __init__(self, elt_name=None, comment=None, level2_objs=None, l1_t2_attr1=None, l1_t2_attr2=None):
        super().__init__(elt_name, comment)
        # List of level2 objects: to be saved in yaml file.
        self.level2_objs = [] if level2_objs is None else level2_objs
        # Attribute: to be saved in yaml file.
        self.l1_t2_attr1 = l1_t2_attr1
        self.l1_t2_attr2 = l1_t2_attr2
        # Dynamic attribute: Not to be saved in yaml file
        self.dyn_data = BunchOfData()

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        dict_representation = {
            'elt_name': node.elt_name,
            'comment': node.comment,
            'level2_objs': node.level2_objs,
            'l1_t2_attr1': node.l1_t2_attr1,
            'l1_t2_attr2': node.l1_t2_attr2
        }
        return representer.represent_mapping(cls.yaml_tag, dict_representation)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        m = {}
        for m in constructor.construct_yaml_map(node):
            pass
        elt_name = m['elt_name'] if 'elt_name' in m else None
        comment = m['comment'] if 'comment' in m else None
        level2_objs = m['level2_objs'] if 'level2_objs' in m else None
        l1_t2_attr1 = m['l1_t2_attr1'] if 'l1_t2_attr1' in m else None
        l1_t2_attr2 = m['l1_t2_attr2'] if 'l1_t2_attr2' in m else None
        return cls(elt_name, comment, level2_objs, l1_t2_attr1, l1_t2_attr2)

    def treatment(self):
        pass


@yaml.register_class
class Level2Type1(Base):

    yaml_tag = u'!Level2Type1'

    def __init__(self, elt_name=None, comment=None, l2_t1_attr1=None):
        super().__init__(elt_name, comment)
        # Attribute: to be saved in yaml file.
        self.l2_t1_attr1 = l2_t1_attr1

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        dict_representation = {
            'elt_name': node.elt_name,
            'comment': node.comment,
            'l2_t1_attr1': node.l2_t1_attr1
        }
        return representer.represent_mapping(cls.yaml_tag, dict_representation)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        m = {}
        for m in constructor.construct_yaml_map(node):
            pass
        elt_name = m['elt_name'] if 'elt_name' in m else None
        comment = m['comment'] if 'comment' in m else None
        l2_t1_attr1 = m['l2_t1_attr1'] if 'l2_t1_attr1' in m else None
        return cls(elt_name, comment, l2_t1_attr1)

    def treatment(self):
        pass


@yaml.register_class
class Level2Type2(Base):

    yaml_tag = u'!Level2Type2'

    def __init__(self, elt_name=None, comment=None, l2_t2_attr1=None, l2_t2_attr2=None):
        super().__init__(elt_name, comment)
        # Attribute: to be saved in yaml file.
        self.l2_t2_attr1 = l2_t2_attr1
        self.l2_t2_attr2 = l2_t2_attr2

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        dict_representation = {
            'elt_name': node.elt_name,
            'comment': node.comment,
            'l2_t2_attr1': node.l2_t2_attr1,
            'l2_t2_attr2': node.l2_t2_attr2
        }
        return representer.represent_mapping(cls.yaml_tag, dict_representation)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        m = {}
        for m in constructor.construct_yaml_map(node):
            pass
        elt_name = m['elt_name'] if 'elt_name' in m else None
        comment = m['comment'] if 'comment' in m else None
        l2_t2_attr1 = m['l2_t2_attr1'] if 'l2_t2_attr1' in m else None
        l2_t2_attr2 = m['l2_t2_attr2'] if 'l2_t2_attr2' in m else None
        return cls(elt_name, comment, l2_t2_attr1, l2_t2_attr2)

    def treatment(self):
        pass


@yaml.register_class
class Level2Type3(Base):

    yaml_tag = u'!Level2Type3'

    def __init__(self, elt_name=None, comment=None, l2_t3_attr1=None, l2_t3_attr2=None, l2_t3_attr3=None):
        super().__init__(elt_name, comment)
        # Attribute: to be saved in yaml file.
        self.l2_t3_attr1 = l2_t3_attr1
        self.l2_t3_attr2 = l2_t3_attr2
        self.l2_t3_attr3 = l2_t3_attr3

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        dict_representation = {
            'elt_name': node.elt_name,
            'comment': node.comment,
            'l2_t3_attr1': node.l2_t3_attr1,
            'l2_t3_attr2': node.l2_t3_attr2,
            'l2_t3_attr3': node.l2_t3_attr3
        }
        return representer.represent_mapping(cls.yaml_tag, dict_representation)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        m = {}
        for m in constructor.construct_yaml_map(node):
            pass
        elt_name = m['elt_name'] if 'elt_name' in m else None
        comment = m['comment'] if 'comment' in m else None
        l2_t3_attr1 = m['l2_t3_attr1'] if 'l2_t3_attr1' in m else None
        l2_t3_attr2 = m['l2_t3_attr2'] if 'l2_t3_attr2' in m else None
        l2_t3_attr3 = m['l2_t3_attr3'] if 'l2_t3_attr3' in m else None
        return cls(elt_name, comment, l2_t3_attr1, l2_t3_attr2, l2_t3_attr3)

    def treatment(self):
        pass

# Make this run.
test = Scenario("my_scenario", "what a scenario may look like after yaml dump",
                [Level1Type1("l1_t1_object", "I am a Level1 Type1 object", [
                    Level2Type1("l2_t1_object", "I am a Level2 Type1 object", 11211),
                    Level2Type2("l2_t2_object", "I am a Level2 Type2 object", 11221, 11222),
                    Level2Type3("l2_t3_object", "I am a Level2 Type3 object", 11231, 11232, 11233),
                ], 111),
                 Level1Type2("l1_t2_object", "I am a Level1 Type2 object", [
                     Level2Type2("l2_t2_object", "I am a Level2 Type2 object", 12221, 12222),
                     Level2Type1("l2_t1_object", "I am a Level2 Type1 object", 12211),
                     Level2Type3("l2_t3_object", "I am a Level2 Type3 object", 12231, 12232, 12233),
                 ], 121, 122)
                 ]
                )
# serialize
dump_buf = StringIO()
yaml.dump(test, dump_buf)
test_serialized = dump_buf.getvalue()
print(test_serialized)
# deserialize
test_is_back = yaml.load(test_serialized)
print(test_is_back)
```

The produced yaml file looks like:

```
!Scenario
elt_name: my_scenario
comment: what a scenario may look like after yaml dump
level1_objs:
- !Level1Type1
  elt_name: l1_t1_object
  comment: I am a Level1 Type1 object
  l1_t1_attr1: 111
  level2_objs:
  - !Level2Type1
    elt_name: l2_t1_object
    comment: I am a Level2 Type1 object
    l2_t1_attr1: 11211
  - !Level2Type2
    elt_name: l2_t2_object
  ....
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a code review site, so I'll restrict myself to the real and IMO implied questions:

As for the real question. No, the `__repr__` is not used by the serialization
process, just to make sure you can "print" the instances and get some human
interpretable representation, instead of `<__module__.Type. object at 0xaddress>` that you would get otherwise.

As for implied question: You are getting a `CommentedSeq` instead of a "normal"
list because you use the, default, round-trip loader/dumper by using

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
```

that loader/dumper needs to be able to attach comments (and anchors/aliases and
tag information for unregistred tags) somewhere and it can do so on
`CommentedSeq` instances as it cannot do that on the build-in `list`.

The `CommentedSeq` behaves in most respect as a `list` but if that is a problem
in one way or another or if you don't need any of the round-trip functionality
(as seems to be in your case), you should just use:

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
```

(which will give you the faster but not fully-compliant C based YAML 1.1 loader/dumper)

Or use:

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe', pure=True)
```

which gives you the loader/dumper without the "overhead" necessar for full round-tripping and thus loading back to `list` instead of `CommentedSeq`.

---

It is possible to write your `from_yaml` methods to do this even with the
round-trip loader, but this is not trivial. But if you are using YAML documents
for dumping and then loading, you should not store any information in comments
and just use the safe dumper/loader.

Comment: First, thanks for this very quick answers and explanations. You're right, there was no big issue in my subject. Nevertheless, I did it to provide an example to others "non pyyaml experts". I have done the code with what i found and there was not so much examples and documentation. In the same time, i was wondering if it was the straight way. I assume that you would have proposed other ways if it was worth (even if it is not a code review area)

Comment: I think the approach is ok. I was slightly thrown of track by the use of `comment` as I am rediesinging the internal comment preserrvation of `ruamel.yaml` in roundtrip mode. So try if the safeloader is enough for what you want to do, that will give you simple lists.

Comment: So yes, if things were completely wrong I would have indicated that. If the answer help solve the issue, please accept it, so others know that this is indeed the/a solution.